# SSIS expression to find previous Friday

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Using SQL Server 2008, I have built an SSIS variable with dynamic value base on current date. I would like to have its value to be Friday if the current day is Monday, and here is the expression built:

```
    DATEPART("dw",GETDATE()) != 2?
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())), 2) + "/" 
    + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())), 2) + "/" + 
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())) : RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE())), 2) + "/" 
    + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("dd", -3, GETDATE())), 2) + "/" + 
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("dd", -1, GETDATE()))
```

Issue: it is not accurate when the month or year changed. Is there any better way to do this? Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a mapping between current day of the week and the desired day of the week? Thus: Monday -> Friday, Tuesday -> Friday, etc Is it always the *next* Friday?

Comment: the variable should have value of '01/11/13' as today's date. If today was Monday (01/14/13), variable would be '01/11/03', another ex: if today is Monday '04/01/13', variable = '03/29/13'. Basically, if the current date on Monday, variable needs to move back 3 days. If current date is not Monday then it will take the current date as a value.

Comment: Your business rule is that if the supplied date's day of the week is Monday, make the value the preceding Friday's date. Otherwise, leave it be?

Comment: yes @billinkc, but make sure it is previous Friday not the coming one.

Comment: If you know it is a monday, why can't you perform a simple `DATEADD( "dd", -3,  GETDATE() )` ? Let `DATEADD()` figure out the proper month and year crossovers. There shouldn't be a need to break it down into its smaller parts, is there?

Comment: @StarPilot how can I keep the format 'mm/dd/yy' in the value of this variable?

Comment: Is your SSIS variable of type DateTime or are you storing that as a string? If the later, is there a specific reason for this requirement?

Comment: You shouldn't really need to worry about 'mm/dd/yy' format.  As long as the variable type is a date, just do date functions on it to manipulate the date and then you can format it within the report. I believe this is what @billinkc is alluding to. Unless you have a special reason why it needs to be a string.

Comment: @billinkc I have the variable of type as DateTime, the SSIS script will not run over the weekend, it will run on Monday to cover Fri, Sat, & Sun.

Answer (score 2):

Will this work (you can substitute `GETDATE()` for `@date`, I just used that to easily test out different dates)

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = '2013-01-14'

SELECT
    PrevFriday = CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @date) <> 2 THEN @date
                      ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -3, @date)
                 END
```

**UPDATE: Here is same, but done in SSIS Variable Expression:**

```
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) != 2?
GETDATE():
DATEADD("dw", -3, GETDATE())
```

**UPDATE #2: Here is how to return the previous Friday for ANY date, not just Monday**

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1 - (DATEPART(weekday, @date) % 7), @date)
```

Comment: I'm using this dynamic variable as a parameter for a stored procedure, and this variable type is date. Some how store procedure doesnt work when using the expression above for the variable. Pls advise