# SSIS Expression for date of previous Friday

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, ssis, sql-server-2012

How can I get the date of a previous Friday using an SSIS expression?
Using below expression:

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)  MONTH(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2)
+ RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR, 4)  YEAR(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())),2)+ ".csv"
```

The output of above expression is `021014.csv`

Comment: Perhaps you'll be better served by stepping back and determining your final state. The rapid fire question without thinking is not what this site is for

Comment: Sorry i am done with my ssis package but i have do it in dynamically using varaibles.

Comment: You have to do some research before you fire some question. In order to get last friday will be 7 days from coming friday or subtract date from today...

Comment: + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)  MONTH(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2) 
+RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(dateadd("d", -DATEPART(weekday,GETDATE()), getdate())), 2)
+RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR, 4)  YEAR(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())),2)+ ".csv"

Comment: I am getting unrecognized token weekday as error

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSIS expression to find previous Friday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284911/ssis-expression-to-find-previous-friday)

Comment: @DataMasseur that question does not have accepted answer and on top of that the answer is flawed it does not give proper result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can also be used :

```
      @[User::Destination] + "_"+ (DT_WSTR,20)
     (
     DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==1? RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)Month (DATEADD ("D", -  1        GETDATE()) ),  2)
     +
     RIGHT ("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2)
     +
     RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2) 
     :
     DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==2? RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)    Month(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2)   
    +
     RIGHT ("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("D",-2,GETDATE())),2)
    +
    RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2) 
    :
    DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==3? RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)    >Month(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2)
    +
    RIGHT ("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("D",-3,GETDATE())),2)
    +
    RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2) 
    :
    DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==4? RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)    >Month(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2)
     +
     RIGHT ("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("D",-4,GETDATE())),2)
     +
     RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2) 
     :
     DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==5? RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)    >Month(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2)
    +
     RIGHT ("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("D",-5,GETDATE())),2)
     +
     RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2) 
     :
     DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==6? RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)Month (DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2)
      +
     RIGHT ("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("D",-6,GETDATE())),2)
      +
      RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2)
      :
      DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==7? RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)    >Month( DATEADD(" D",-1,   GETDATE()     )),2)
        +
       RIGHT ("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("D",-7,GETDATE())),2)
        + 
        RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("D",-1,GETDATE())),2)
        : "" )
         +".csv"
```

Comment: Format your answer, otherwise people see just ton of garbage.

Comment: Its waorking you are aweosome!!

Answer (score 0):

This is using T-SQL, you will still need to convert for SSIS. This is more of hint that an answer. But could not fit it into a comment.

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = '02/15/2014' --Saturday
--Returns Date for Friday that was last week. When current date is Saturday will return Friday that was 1 week ago.
SELECT DATEADD(dd,-DATEPART(weekday,@CurrentDate)-1,@CurrentDate)   --Output: 2014-02-07
--Returns Date for most recent Friday.
SELECT  DATEADD(dd,-(DATEPART(weekday,@CurrentDate)%7+1),@CurrentDate)  --Output: 2014-02-14

SET @CurrentDate = '02/11/2014' --Tuesday
SELECT DATEADD(dd,-DATEPART(weekday,@CurrentDate)-1,@CurrentDate)   --Output: 2014-02-07
SELECT  DATEADD(dd,-(DATEPART(weekday,@CurrentDate)%7+1),@CurrentDate)  --Output: 2014-02-07
```

You need to figure out what is your requirement for getting Friday, is it Friday of last complete week, or just last Friday whereas it is current week or previous.

Comment: :i need friday it is current week or previous .I am good with tsql query but i want to generate using varaibles .

Comment: in that case you need the second expression `SELECT DATEADD(dd,-(DATEPART(weekday,GETDATE())%7+1),GETDATE())` just replace `GETDATE()` with your variables or your columns.