# SSIS expression to find date of the Friday given week number

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, connection-string, week-number

I am trying to create an expression for a connection string to give me the the date given a week number and if possible, the date for the Friday of that week.

This is what I'm aiming for output: **Week9 - 24 Feb 2017** (I already have a variable expression for the month name)

There is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14286492) which gives the date of last friday:

```
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) != 2?
GETDATE():
DATEADD("dw", -3, GETDATE())
```

but it's not in connection string form.

This is what I'm using to derive my week number if it helps:

```
Right("" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("ww", DateAdd("ww", -2, getdate())), 2)
```

Thanks,

J

Comment: what you mean by **Connection string** date expression??

Comment: I'd like to know that too

Comment: You want to append week number in file name?

Comment: @Hadi So I want to use it as an expression for the connection string of my flat file connection manager and so it needs to be in a similar form to this     `Right("" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("ww", DateAdd("ww", -2, getdate())), 2)`

Comment: @KinchitDalwani Yes, but I have the week number, I now want the date based on that week number

Comment: @JamesBracky can you mention the excpected output!

Comment: @KinchitDalwani just edited my original post to include it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Side Notes:*

- *First at all it is good to read about [Modifying the Flat File Connection Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166797.aspx)*
- *You can use a [third party SSIS expression evaluator](https://expressioneditor.codeplex.com/) to test an expression without starting a new SSIS project*

**Solution**

After reading the answer you provided in your question this is the expression that return the last friday:

```
DATEADD("dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", @date) % 7), @date)
```

To Get your expected output you have to use an expression like the following:

*I asume that you want to build a connection string (file path) like the following `C:\NewFolder\Week7 - 24 Feb 2017\File.txt`*

In this answer i used `GETDATE()` function as a date value

```
"C:\\NewFolder\\Week" + Right("" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("ww", DateAdd("ww", -2, GETDATE())), 2) + " - " + (DT_STR,20,1252)DAY(DATEADD("dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) % 7), GETDATE()) ) + " " + (DT_STR,20,1252)(MONTH(GETDATE()) == 1 ? "Jan" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 2 ? "Feb" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 3 ? "Mar" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 4 ? "Apr" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 5 ? "May" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 6 ? "Jun" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 7 ? "Jul" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 8 ? "Aug" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 9 ? "Sep" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 10 ? "Oct" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 11 ? "Nov" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 12 ? "Dec" : "NA") + " " +  (DT_STR,20,1252)YEAR( DATEADD("dd", -1  - (DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) % 7),GETDATE() )) + "\\File.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that is the output that I wanted. However, when I use your expression, it doesn't give me the last Friday, it gives me the day 2 days before today's date and I have to manually change the -1 value to -2 in this part of it: 
`DAY(DATEADD("dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) % 7), GETDATE()) )`
Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesBracky this is the expression found in the answer you provided. I will try to search for another one. Happy to help